# Magento: Saving new customer in onepage checkout

Tags: magento, registration, checkout

I am a relative novice at Magento (and new to stackoverflow, so bear with me).  My client is running a rather old community version (1.4).

They have set up checkout with **Onepage checkout = YES**, and **Guest checkout allowed = NO**.

What they discovered is that when new customers register as part of checkout, the **customer record is not getting created**.  This seems like a pretty glaring error but in all my searching I can’t find anything to suggest that anyone is having this problem.

All of my research pointed to the **submitOrder method of Quote.php** as the place to look and I found this code:

```
 if ($quote->getCustomerId()) {
            $transaction->addObject($quote->getCustomer());
        }
```

When I set a breakpoint at this point I (as I expected) found that this new customer has NO id, so the Customer object never gets added to the transaction.

Really, this seemed too obvious a problem so I kept exploring expecting to find that the Customer gets saved elsewhere, but found nothing.  So, as a test, I changed the code to be:

```
 if (!$quote->getCustomerId()) {
            $transaction->addObject($quote->getCustomer());
      }
```

Well, the Customer and the Order got saved just as I hoped.  But this seems WAY too obvious and might create issues for me if I want to save changes to customer data for existing Customers.  But, I can deal with that for now.

I looked ahead in V1.8 to see if somehow this problem got fixed in a newer version and the code is the same.  That, and the fact that I can’t find any report of this problems makes me think I am not looking in the right place and have just put a convenient patch on the problem.

**Can anyone help me out with this?  Am I in the right place or way off base?  Please advise!**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [magento.se]

Comment: Thanks, I agree, but I posted there on their Technical Forum and have gotten no response.  The Technical Forum is being flooded with what looks like Vietnamese spam entries causing my entry to get pushed back.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you meant the Magento Stackexchange.  Thx, will try that.